# how to change log file creation user in linux

Tags: linux, logs, ownership

Log files are being created with the root user:

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root xxxx Mar 14 16:53 access_log.1489489200
```

What is the process to change it to another user? like:

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 user user xxxx Mar 14 16:53 access_log.1489489200
```

Comment: Which program is creating the logs?

Comment: To change: `sudo chown user:user access_log.*`

Answer (score 0):

As written by @Stephen, you can change the logfiles' owner via the command

```
chown user:user access_log.*
```

However, what you should do is to identify the program which is creating the logs, and see how this program can be run as the `user` user instead of the `root` user.